# Always On DTC Support on new database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups

Is it possible in SQL Server 2016 Enterprise to add a new database to an Always On availability group and have it enabled for DTC support without recreating the AG?

Our Availability Group is already set for DTC support on the databases already existing but we are creating a new database and it needs to have DTC support as well. Can this be done with some kind of Alter statement or would we have to take an outage and totally recreate the AG group when we add each database that needs DTC?

Comment: If the AG is already created with DTC_SUPPORT=PER_DB then you're fine, just add the database in. Having said that, I hope your DTC infrastructure design is up to the challenge.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the case. We have DTC_Support = PER_DB set but only defined the existing databases.  For example
CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP MyAG
   WITH (
      DTC_SUPPORT = PER_DB  
      )
   FOR DATABASE DB1, DB2

Comment: When you add the database in, it'll get the properties of the AG which already had it set. All of the databases in the AG have the properties set for the AG.